# Checkbox, don't allow it to be checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I've got a check box designed and styled like this:

```
<div class='checkbox'>
    <label for="test">
    <div class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" name='test' id='test' value="1"/>
        <div class="slider"></div>
    </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on the checkbox, I'm calling an external page and getting a return value. If the value <= 0 then I need to stop the checkbox being checked.

This the Jquery I'm using that doesn't work..

```
$("body").on('change', '#test', function(){
    var check = $(this).attr('id')
    if (document.getElementById(check).checked) {
        $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
            url: "do.php?mode=check=" + check,   
            async: true,
            success : function(text) {
            console.log (text)
            if (text === '0') 
                $('#test').attr('checked', false);
            }   
        });
    }
})
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fyLLyqv7/)**

How can I update the styled checkbox so it is unchecked and shows as unchecked onscreen ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you tell us what the `console.log(text)` returns? I have a feeling that the returned "text" variable is an object containing a node with your 0 or 1.

Comment: it shows 0, that is being returned via a php echo.

Comment: I see. Can you try `$("#test").prop("checked",false)` instead of using the attr() function? The .attr() function is deprecated as ofjquery 1.6.

Comment: thanks thats worked :)

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance.

Comment: I've you want to add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(element).attr()` function is deprecated as of jquery 1.6. You should use `$("#test").prop("checked",false)` instead.

From the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.

Comment: Thanks that sorted it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `disabled` attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" name='test' id='test' value="1" disabled />
```

This disables the unchecked checkbox. You can remove it with JavaScript if you wish to have the user check it again. But in your case, i'd go with a manual jQuery check.

Disable by default, then have the ajax request go through as soon as the user clicks on it. After that, do something like:

```
if(callback =< 0) { $('#checkbox').prop('checked', true) }
```

More about disabled [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)